# A phrase for something that is beyond our reach or unattainable

Tags: phrases, metaphors

“Sir Francis Chichester was knighted by the queen. But for his other circumnavigating counterparts, a knighthood is *beyond reach*...”

What is an alternative term for *beyond reach*?

Comment: Why is _beyond reach_ or _unattainable_ not good enough? What do they lack that you are looking for?

Comment: Why not just "unattainable?" It literally means "not able to be reached or achieved." I know it's a single word, rather than a phrase, but it seems you've answered your own question.

Comment: I want it to be more dramatic like "A distant Fruit"... suggestions?

Comment: ‘A distant fruit’ is highly unidiomatic and sounds almost bizarre to me. **Far out of reach** is quite common and sounds both poetic and dramatic.

Comment: I get your point.

Comment: It'd be **unthinkable** to grant some of those tarry old sea dogs nobility.

Comment: Some broader stylistic suggestions.  I'm not sure what you're aiming for, but I find the phrase _his other circumnavigating counterparts_ (unintentionally) comical.  How about, less verbosely, _other circumnavigators_ or _his rival circumnavigators_.  (Also, out of context, it is hard to judge whether the shift to narrative present flows naturally.  It risks sounding clunky.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to mention an interesting phrase: ***[ultima thule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thule)***

> The term **ultima Thule** in medieval geographies denotes any distant place located beyond the "borders of the known world".
>
> Virgil coined the term Ultima Thule (Georgics, 1. 30) meaning furthest land as a symbolic reference to denote a far-off land or **an unattainable goal.**

It is still used today in this symbolic sense.

---

Other than that, there is ***[a pipe dream](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+pipe+dream)***

> an idea that could never happen because it is impossible
>
> *The classless society is just a pipe dream.*

---

And finally, there is ***[will-o'-the-wisp](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will-o%27-the-wisp)***

> a goal that cannot be reached, a delusive or elusive goal

It originally means the atmospheric ghost lights seen at night over marshy grounds. But it is used in this symbolic sense in literature.

---

**Note:** All of the phrases fit to your example also.

Answer (score 1):

A suitably inappropriate metaphor is:

> "a million miles away".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That must go well with the sentence but i want something that is more dramatic, adding a flavor that makes your inside chuckle for a nanosecond. :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might work: *still a world away.*

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

> “Sir Francis Chichester was knighted by the queen. But for his other circumnavigating counterparts, a knighthood is *not even an option.”
>
> “Sir Francis Chichester was knighted by the queen. But for his other circumnavigating counterparts, a knighthood is *nowhere near conceivable.”

Comment: I guess the second one does really good. Thankyou ellan. You made my day!

Comment: @NarendraRao You're very welcome. :-)